my subset selector using Ngrx isn't working
i'm using Angular 17 with ngrx.
I have the following selectors that work fine:
export const getPhotoState = createFeatureSelector<ProductResponse>('selectedPhotos');

export const selectPhotos = createSelector(getPhotoState, (state: ProductResponse) => { return state.results });

export const PhotoCount = createSelector(getPhotoState, (state: ProductResponse) => { return state.item_Count });

I dont want to write another effect/reducer to go off to the server as I just want to get a subset of the data already returned.
I have written the following:
export const XboxPhotos = createSelector(selectPhotos, (reducedPhotos) => {
  return xboxPhotos('xbox', reducedPhotos)
})

function xboxPhotos(key: string, array: any) {
  return array.reduce((all: Product[], current: Product) => {
    if (current.platform == key) {
      all.push(current);
    }
  }, []) as Product[]
}

I receive an error of :

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

reducedPhotos is Product[]

Return the value after operations
function xboxPhotos(key: string, array: any) {
  return array.reduce((all: Product[], current: Product) => {
    if (current.platform == key) {
      all.push(current);
    }
    return all; // <- changed here
  }, []) as Product[]
}


You are modifying the accumulator (in this case, the all array) but never returning it. If you return all at the end of the reducer callback, you'll not see this error anymore.
